# Method Chaining causes compilation errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, method-chaining

When I try to write a one line with a chain of methods as shown below, I get a compilation error:

```
int index=data.getPlayer1().getIndex();
```

The error in this case is

> Invalid arguments

But when I divide the chain, everything works out fine:

```
Player player1=data.getPlayer1();
int index=player1.getIndex();
```

All of these methods are part of the same namespace and the #include notations are in order. How can I solve this issue?

Edit:

The getters are shown below:

```
    const Player& getPlayer1() const {
    return player1;
}

int getIndex() { return index;}
```

Comment: show us the code for getPlayer1 and getIndex?

Comment: How are these functions declared? I think it has to with the function signatures.

Comment: I just edited the question to include the functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getPlayer()` returns a `const Player&` but `getIndex()` is a non-`const` member function and it is illegal to call a non-`const` member function on a `const` object. Make `getIndex()` `const` (as it should be anyway as it is a getter and does not modify the object):

```
int getIndex() const { return index; }
             //^^^^^
```

It works in the split case:

```
Player player1=data.getPlayer1();
```

because of *copy* of `Player` is being made, and `player1` is not a `const` object and `getIndex()` can be invoked.

Comment: It works. But just a question about the edit. Why is a copy made in the split case? The getter returns by reference and not value.

Comment: @Sami, yes but the type of `player1` is `Player`, not `Player&` or `const Player&` so a copy is made.